# Javascript - Ajax onload Callback Fail

Tags: javascript

I want to make an `ajax` function using plain `javascript`. I am able to do it using the normal `onload` callback but if I want to do it on a define function, it fails.

May I know what is the mistakes and How to do it? Below are the codes,

```
function ajax (url, method) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    xhr.onload = onloadUpdate();

    //xhr.send(data)
}

function onloadUpdate () {
    console.log(this.responseText);
    // the result is undefined

   // other codes for success update notification
}

ajax('sample-site.dev', 'POST');
```

Comment: `xhr.onload = onloadUpdate();` assigns the *result* of (immediately) calling `onloadUpdate` to the `onload` handler. You don't want that - assign the plain function instead, rather than the result of the called function. `xhr.onload = onloadUpdate;`

Comment: `xhr.onerror = errCallback` is sufficient.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks the help. Let say if I want to check a condition on the `onloadUpdate` function. For example, I want to check `if(this.responseText == 'success')` on the function. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @AdamAzad, the error that I get is `Unable to get property 'remove' of undefined or null reference`